# How to specify file paths in a compressed way?

Tags: python, repository, file-management

I'm in need fo specifying file paths to sort JSON files that gets retreived from an API. I have a class module that saves and loads the files

```
import os
import json

class Directory:

    def __init__(self):
        self.working_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__) #Get's the current working directory


    def mkdir(self, *path):
        """Creates folder in the same level as the working directory folder

            Args:
                *args: path to folder that is to be created
        """
        target_dir = os.path.join(self.working_dir, *path)
        try: 
            if os.path.exists(target_dir) == True:
                print(target_dir, 'exists')
            else:
                os.mkdir(os.path.join(self.working_dir, *path))
                print(os.path.join(self.working_dir, *path), 'succesfully created')
        except OSError as e:
            print(folder,'coult not be created', e)

    def check_if_file_exist(self, *path):
        if os.path.exists(os.path.join(self.working_dir, *path)):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def save_json(self, filename, content, *path):
            """save dictionarirys to .json files        
            Args:
                file (str): The name of the file that is to be saved in .json format
                filename (dict): The dictionary that is to be wrote to the .json file
                folder (str): The folder name in the target directory
            """
            target_dir = os.path.join(self.working_dir, *path)
            file_dir = os.path.join(self.working_dir, target_dir, filename) 
            with open(file_dir + '.json', "w") as f:
                #pretty prints and writes the same to the json file
                f.write(json.dumps(content, indent=4, sort_keys=False))
```

But it often result in hideously long lines when a file-path has to be specified, for example.

```
#EXAMPLE
filename = self.league + '_' + year + '_' + 'fixturestats'
self.dir.save_json(filename, stats, '..', 'json', 'params', 'stats')
path = '/'.join(('..', 'json', 'params'))

#OTHER EXAMPLE
league_season_info = self.dir.load_json('season_params.json', '..', 'json', 'params')
```

I'm wondering what optimal praxis is when having a repository that has rather static folders relative to the working directory. All my modules are now build to create the folders that are needed in the repository if they do not exist, so I can count on that the paths exist when loading or saving files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the party, but here's how I might do it. As you mention these folders are fairly static, they can be placed into a configuration object of sorts (e.g. as class members of the thing owning `dir`, or a stand-alone object). Since I do not know your class structure, I'll opt for a standalone object.

This might look like the following, using [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#basic-use):*

```
from pathlib import Path

class StorageConfig:
  STORAGE_BASE_DIR = Path("json")
  PARAMS_DIR = STORAGE_BASE_DIR / "params"
  STATS_DIR = PARAMS_DIR / "stats"

  # Etc.
```

This can be used as follows:

```
self.dir.save_json(filename, stats, StorageConfig.STATS_DIR)
params = self.dir.load_json('season_params.json', StorageConfig.PARAMS_DIR)
```

Or, doing away with the directory argument altogether:

```
self.dir.save_json(StorageConfig.STATS_DIR / (filename + ".json"), stats)
params = self.dir.load_json(StorageConfig.PARAMS_DIR / 'season_params.json')
```

*Pathlib can simplify most of the code currently in your `Directory` class. Have a look!

Comment: Thank you very much for your input, this does indeed look very neat and is what I'm looking for! Glad you found my post, thank you!